# Bode plot phase shift equation when poles and zeros are not at the origin

Tags: transfer-function, frequency-domain, laplace-transform, bode

Let $$H(s)=\frac{s^{n}}{s^{m}}$$
For $n \ne m$ the phase shift between output and input will be
$\frac{\pi}{2}(n-m)$.

For situations where the poles and zeros are not at the origin, I could find the phase $\Phi(s)= \frac{\Im[H(s)]}{\Re[H(s)]}$ but I am asking if there is a shorter process.

For example if the transfer function was $$\frac{(s-a_{1})(s-a_{2})...(s-a_{n})}{(s-b_{1})(s-b_{2})...(s-b_{n})}$$which would be the equation for the phase shift?

Comment: Hi Cerise, you're really asking us to repeat what is in your "signals and systems" textbook. That's too broad. You will need to tell us where exactly you're stuck understanding this – do you understand how to calculate the phase of from $H(s)$? Do you not understand how to insert $s$ into $H(s)$? We can't start telling you how to do math starting at the first semester. **Your job**, as asker of a question, is make clear how far you've gotten, and ask a precise question.

Comment: @MarcusMüller sure I could find the phase = $\frac{Im[H(s)]}{Re[H(s]}$ but I am asking if there is a shorter process.

Comment: you don't say so in your question, you asked something else. I'm editing it for you (you should have clarified that to begin with). However, what allows you to assume a "shorter process" would exist?

Comment: More of a simplified result instead of having to do the same thing over and over again.Just like we have the simplified result for poles and zeros at the origin.

Comment: @Cerise I'm not sure how it would be theoretically possible to take the distance from 2×n points in less than 2×n operations? That seems to make no sense to me. What shortcut did you have in mind? Could you explain *why* you assume there would be a shorter process? The process is just "evaluate a rational function", and that  already seems to be a simple thing to do, no? Seeing there's 2n parameters, a straightforward evaluation of the denominator and enumerator polynomial from product form as in your question seems optimal, unless you can constrain values $a_i,b_i$ and forgot to mention that.